# Web Server Issue with Concurrency

Tags: python, multithreading, http

I am a new Python learner and I want to implement a simple web server that can deal with multi-threads. If I do not make the line`conn.close()` a comment, everything works well. Problems would occur if I make `conn.close()` a comment. A client can successfully get the response after first request but when I refresh the web page, the browser would fail to receive the response. Is there anyone who can tell me how to fix this? Is there something wrong with my code?

```
import socket
import threading
import time


class MyServer:
    def __init__(self, port, doc_root):
        self.port = port
        self.doc_root = doc_root
        self.host = "localhost"

    def run(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as soc:
            soc.bind((self.host, self.port))
            soc.listen(5)
            req = b''
            while True:
                conn, addr = soc.accept()
                threading.Thread(target=self.handle_connection, args=(conn, addr)).start()

    def handle_connection(self, conn, addr):
        assert isinstance(conn, socket.socket)
        req = b''
        while b'\r\n\r\n' not in req:
            req += conn.recv(1024)
        print(addr)
        print(req.decode())
        time.sleep(0.5)
        conn.sendall(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello World')
        print(addr, 'response sent')
        # conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_port = 8006
    input_doc_root = r'/'
    server = MyServer(input_port, input_doc_root)
    server.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `conn.close()` because refreshing the browser without the server closing the connection will lead to the request being sent down that very same connection. Your handle ends after sending one response; there's simply nothing reading from and writing to that socket after the first request-response conversation in your code.

On a side note, I also had a few issues with omitting `conn.close()` on the client side, at least with the browser I tested. Since you don't tell your clients when they can stop reading from their side's socket, FF kept reading its endpoint, even after rendering the full response.

If you put your `recv` and `sendall` into some loop and give the clients some hint as to when the data has been fully received, it will work:

```
def handle_connection(self, conn, addr):
    assert isinstance(conn, socket.socket)
    while conn:
        req = b''
        while b'\r\n\r\n' not in req:
            req += conn.recv(1024)
        print(addr)
        print(req.decode())
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # Note Content-Lenght in the 'header' below 
        # to let the clients know when to stop reading
        conn.sendall(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 11\r\n\r\nHello World')
        print(addr, 'response sent')
        # conn.close()
```

However, closing the connection after sending the response is the right thing to do, IMHO. You cannot rely on the clients always closing the connections properly, so you risk wasting resources on what effectively are stale sessions. With the solution outlined above, the threads tend to stick around for some time, basically waiting for nothing.

In the end, HTTP is stateless, so there is no real point in maintaining the connection beyond sending the response.

Comment: Thank you so much for anwering. Actually I want to optionally close the socket or not according to the request header. If it contails Connection: close, then I shall add `conn.close()`, otherwise I want to keep the connection alive. In this case, is it right to not close the connection?

Comment: You absolutely _can_ do that. You just need to find a way to determine the end of a connection without relying on external clients to do the right thing to end it, like idle-timeouts. Keep in mind that connections waiting to time out block resources. Keep in mind that with persistent connections, the clients must be told when to stop reading (e.g. Content-Length or [chunked Transfer-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)). Also keep in mind that the Connection header field has been removed in [HTTP 2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.2).